# kpartx verbose info: what does it mean?

Tags: linux, partition, parted, kpartx

When mounting images with the wonderful kpartx in verbose mode it displays some, likely very useful, information:

```
# kpartx -av wheezy_cln.img 
add map loop0p1 (252:2): 0 131072 linear /dev/loop0 2048
add map loop0p2 (252:3): 0 7825408 linear /dev/loop0 133120
```

I can guess, but does anyone know exactly what these numbers are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **loop0p1**: device mapper name
- **(252:2)**: major:minor of the device
- **0**: starting block of the map (I've never seen anything else than 0)
- **131072**: size of the device in blocks
- **/dev/loop0**: parent device
- **2048**: starting block (block 0 of loop0p1 is block 2048 of loop0)

Also see `dmsetup table DEVICE`